# Img Src tag in Html not Working regardless any reference link type

Tags: html, image, tags

I was editing an HTML page and had some issue in replacing image. It didn't displayed anything.
Then I tried making a simple HTML program just to test

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>

<img src="/images/Kanhaji.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" width="128" height="128" />


</body>
</html>
```

but it still doesnot work.
I tried Everything Including but not limited to
 
1. Giving local links in same directory in which my page is.
2. Creating a subDirectory and giving its link.(as shown above)
3. Giving full path
4. using `<image src="./Kanhaji.jpeg" />` (proper reference methods `./` `../` etc)
5. Using an Online Link `<image src="https://I_cannot_remember_the_url_exactly />` 
6. Hard Refreshing page <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f5</kbd> in case if browser is using cached contents somehow.
 But nothing seems to work
only a box,where image is supposed to appears, with a broken image icon appears.

`<img class="rounded-circle img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">` 
 the above code is working fine
after watching it working , i tried to 
7.remove extension of file if it is effecting somehow but that also didn't helped

Can anyone help me with this problem.

Comment: The code is okay. We don't know where image is located and if the name is correct. We can't help you more.

Comment: That happens in multiple browsers? Did you check the console for errors? Disable all your plugins/addons/extensions?

Comment: it has one error related to document declaration only....The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

Comment: @panther i don't have any plugins/addons/extensions enabled. not even any adblock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your image in a browser and you can see real path in address bar, if you testing in localhost... and tell us about your path for a help you.

Comment: okk there may be a problem with my browser.. it is not showing image in this situation 
`right click> open with> firefox` 
shows the same error image

Comment: You can try drag image in a tab of browser or to blank page.

Answer (score 0):

The above html structure should be fine. I'd recommend checking the following:

- Whether the server has altered your code and replaced the URL of the image in the html.
- Is the image itself in a folder on the server that is publicly accessible? What happens if you just type the complete URL of image to the location bar of your browser?
- Confirm that the name of the file and filename in the "src" tag are the same. I misspelled filenames more times than I would like to admit (first capital letter vs. all smallcaps).
- Check the file type. Even if the extension says "jpg", it might have a different format, and some browsers may fail to recognize it.

Anyway, if you could provide the url of your site, it would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing . Before the /image.
It's leads to the subfolder where your image is kept.

```
<img> src="./images/Kanhaji.jpg" alt="HTML5 Icon" width="128" height="128"/>
```

Comment: point 4: i tried everything including proper reference methods i.e i already tried your solution but it did not worked

Answer (score 0):

Okk guys i Think There was a problem with my browser.. when i tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49410018/8543493) answer ... it failed to open directly as well.. i reinstalled Firefox and its working now.. but was not able to found the cause of problem